# java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file

Tags: java

I was trying to move file using move file method .but getting this error
"`java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file`"

this is my code.

this is for file move without error

```
public void moveWithoutError(String fileName){

     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String ts = dateFormat.format(date);

        File source = new File("D:/Inbound/");    
        File dest = new File("D:/Archive/"); 

        for (File file : source.listFiles()) {

            String x = (source + "/" + file.getName());
           String y = (dest + "/" + addTimestamp(file.getName(), ts));

           if(file.getName().equals(fileName)){
               File sourceFile = new File(x);
               File destnFile = new File(y);
               try{
                   FileUtils.moveFile(sourceFile, destnFile);
                   System.out.println("Moved file:"+y);
               }catch(Exception e){
                   System.out.println("Unable to move file:"+y);
                   System.out.println(e);
                                        e.printStackTrace();

               }
               break;
           }
       }
}
```

This code is written for moving the file with containing error

```
public void moveWithError(String fileName){

     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String ts = dateFormat.format(date);

        File source = new File("D:/Inbound\\"); 
        File dest = new File("D:\\Error\\"); /

        for (File file : source.listFiles()) {

            String x = (source + "/" + file.getName());
            String y = (dest + "/" + addTimestamp(file.getName(), ts));

            if(file.getName().equals(fileName)){
                   File f1 = new File(x); 
                    if(f1.renameTo(new File(y))){
                       System.out.println(" moved: " + y);
                    } else {
                      System.out.println("unable to move: " + y);
                    }
                    break;
               }


        }

}
```

This code is used to add timestamp to moved file

```
public static String addTimestamp(String name, String ts) {
    int lastIndexOf = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    return (lastIndexOf == -1 ? 
            name + "_" + ts 
            : 
            name.substring(0, lastIndexOf) + "-" + ts + 
            name.substring(lastIndexOf))
             .replaceAll("[\\/:\\*\\?\"<>| ]", "");
}

}
```

while executing this code exception come
abd exception is 
"java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'D:\Inbound\Testdata.xlsx' after copy to 'D:\Archive\Testdata-20140812121814.xlsx'"

Note - this file is nor open neither accessing by other process
Please help :(

Exception

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'D:\Inbound\Testdata.xlsx' after copy to 'D:\Archive\Testdata-20140812130655.xlsx' 
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2664) 
at CRP.MoveFile.moveWithoutError (MoveFile.java:77) 
at CRP.CRPDAO.callMoveFile (CRPDAO.java:562) 
at CRP.CRP_FileDependency.main (CRP_FileDependency.java:163)
```

Comment: Have you checked the ownership and permissions on the Inbound file? Does your process have the necessary rights to delete the file?

Comment: yes i have created the file and able to delete it manually

Comment: This code doesn't print that exception. Please post the stack trace and the code that prints it. NB code quality alert: `f1` is identical to `file` here. You don't need it twice. Ergo you don't need `x`. And you don't need to create `y` unless it's a matching filename.

Comment: could you please help me with code?

Comment: *Please post the stack trace.* And I've *already* helped you with the code you posted.

Comment: stack trace prints-java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'D:\Inbound\Testdata.xlsx' after copy to 'D:\Archive\Testdata-20140812130655.xlsx'
 at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2664)
 at CRP.MoveFile.moveWithoutError(MoveFile.java:77)
 at CRP.CRPDAO.callMoveFile(CRPDAO.java:562)
 at CRP.CRP_FileDependency.main(CRP_FileDependency.java:163)

Comment: Great. You can see for yourself that it is completely illegible in a comment. Please edit it into your question and format it as code.

Comment: but still i am getting the same exception

Comment: I don't know why you think editing your question will magically cure an exception, but it won't. What it *will* do is enable other people to see what on earth you're talking about. If all you're doing is trying to bump your question, please don't.

Comment: Mr.EJP if you are  not able to solve my issue its completely fine but stop giving your meaningless suggestion

Comment: His suggestions are not meaningless at all, for instance I came to your question in the hope I could help someone (you) but I have to dig in the comment to get more information. That is not handy at all and discourages me (and since your problem does not seem so hard and lots of persons have seen it and people on this site are generally willing to help I'd say it discourages most people).
The problem here is that we lack information as to how your problem occurred. With more informations we might help you solve this.